Using @MainActor on ObservableObject gives warning about publishing changes from background thread
While working on a simple app to learn more about SwiftUI I get the runtime warning

Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

The warning occurs on the published value of a ObservableObject. I understand that I'm attempting to change a published value from a background thread, the value gets changes based on the response of a web request. From what I could find the problem should be resolved by adding @MainActor to the ObservableObject or by specifying the update to be done on the main thread with DispatchQueue.main.async { }, but both options don't seem to work.
@MainActor
class AuthStore: ObservableObject {
    var authState: OIDAuthState?

    @Published var isAuthenticated = false // <-- The warning is about this line

    func login() {
        // Set the necessary configuration like client ID and redirect URI.
        // The config is also loaded.

        // performs authentication request
        self.appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: scene!.keyWindow!.rootViewController!) { authState, error in
            if let authState = authState {
                self.setAuthState(authState)
                print("Got authorization tokens!")
                self.retrieveCookies()
            } else {
                print("Authorization error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                self.setAuthState(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    private func setAuthState(_ authState: OIDAuthState?) {
        if (self.authState == authState) {
            return;
        }
        
        self.authState = authState


        // I've also tried it by surrounding this line with DispatchQueue.main.async { }
        // and removing the @MainActor from the class.
        self.isAuthenticated = authState?.isAuthorized == true
    }
}

The isAuthenticated value is used in the main class of the app.
@main
struct MyLearningApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var authStore = AuthStore()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if authStore.isAuthenticated {
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(authStore)
            } else {
                LoginView()
                    .environmentObject(authStore)
            }
        }
    }
}

For completeness sake the AppDelegate class which is required to use the AppAuth library in Swift.
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var currentAuthorizationFlow: OIDExternalUserAgentSession?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        // Sends the URL to the current authorization flow (if any) which will
        // process it if it relates to an authorization response.
        if let authorizationFlow = self.currentAuthorizationFlow, authorizationFlow.resumeExternalUserAgentFlow(with: url) {
            self.currentAuthorizationFlow = nil
            return true
        }
        
        // Your additional URL handling (if any)
        
        return false
    }
}

Note that I'm using the AppAuth library to login a user through Keycloak.
Edit
I've attempted to resolve the problem by converting the login() method by using a continuation for the callback of the AppAuth library method I'm using, but that doesn't seem to work (I'm probably doing something wrong):
func login() async {
    // Set the necessary configuration like client ID and redirect URI.
    // The config is also loaded.

    // performs authentication request
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        self.appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: scene!.keyWindow!.rootViewController!) { authState, error in
            if let authState = authState {
                self.setAuthState(authState)
                print("Got authorization tokens!")
                self.retrieveCookies()
            } else {
                print("Authorization error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                self.setAuthState(nil)
            }
            continuation.resume()
        }
    }
}

Alternatively I've tried to resolve the warning by using a completion, but that produces the same result:
class AuthStore: ObservableObject {
    var authState: OIDAuthState?

    @Published var isAuthenticated = false // <-- The warning is about this line

    func loginTest() {
        login() { auth in
            if let authState = auth {
                self.setAuthState(authState)
                print("Got authorization tokens. Access token: \(authState.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken ?? "nil")")
                self.retrieveCookies()
            } else {
                self.setAuthState(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func login(_ completion: @escaping ((OIDAuthState?) -> Void)) {
        // Set the necessary configuration like client ID and redirect URI.
        // The config is also loaded.

        // performs authentication request
        self.appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: scene!.keyWindow!.rootViewController!) { authState, error in
            if let authState = authState {
                completion(authState)
            } else {
                completion(nil))
            }
        }
    }
}

Apparently I've been reading the warning of Xcode wrong. Adding Task { @MainActor in } around the line setting the published is authenticated value (self.isAuthenticated = authState?.isAuthorized == true) does work. After doing that the warning was resolved for that line, but the same warning applied to the published value beneath it (which I omitted from my question) which is changed in a different method that makes an HTTP request.
The Xcode warning which is about the cookies value and not the isAuthenticated value:

I am still confused as to why adding the @MainActor annotation to the AuthStore class doesn't resolve the warnings and removing the annotation and adding Task { @MainActor in } around the lines that update the published values does.

Unlike async/await contents of completion handlers are not dispatched to the main actor automatically. Wrap the self.isAuthenticated = … line in a Task { @MainActor in  block.

Is there a difference between using Task { @MainActor in } and DispatchQueue.main.async { }? Anyways, wrapping self.isAuthenticated = true with either doesn't resolve the warning.

Convert completion handlers to async/await. You can get guidance from “Meet async/await” actors aren’t compatible with the old threading practices.

Although both forms do basically the same it's not recommended to mix GCD with async/await. Regarding your edit the resume line must be inside the completion block

Good to know! Then I'll prefer to use Task { @MainActor in } instead of DispatchQueue.main.async { } when using async/await like in the code in my question.
Whoops, I missed that it wasn't in the completion block. Originally I forgot the resume entirely and got a complaint about the login method leaking. Adding the resume outside the completion block fixed that so I missed it was still not right. I've fixed the code in the question.

I would suggest changing the “Strict concurrency checking” build setting to “Complete”. The compiler would then warn you of the problems in the above code.
